# PHP - Defer Loader?

Tags: php, include

I have a function which loads a class or file. It works something like this.

```
function load ( $type, $path, $file ) {
  ...
  switch($type) {
    case 'file':
      ....
      include $path . '/' . $file;
    break;
  }
}
```

It works perfectly for classes. It also works well for files containing functions / html. However, if I get a file which contains variables I run into the problem of scope. Is there a simple way to pass the variables from the load function into whatever is calling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to pass the variables from the load function into whatever is calling it?

Nope. `load()` has its own variable scope, and the included file inherits that scope.

You would have to pass all relevant variables as parameters to the `load()` function, or, if possible, access the variables using `$GLOBALS` (yuck!)

One workaround could be returning the file path from `load()` instead of including it:

```
return $path . '/' . $file;
```

and calling it like so:

```
$path = load(".....");
if ($path) include $path;
```

this would include the file in the original scope.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to solve this to ensure that my configuration files contained objects instead of variables. This wiped out the scope problem as variables could be called statically.

```
$user = database::user;
```

This solution also make's it far easier to dynamically change config settings while the application is running.